# c++ Eigen: spline derivatives() gives strange derivatives

Tags: c++, eigen, spline

I'm trying to get a hold on how to work with splines in Eigen, specifically I want do find the value of the spline interpolation and its first and second derivatives in some point. Finding the interpolated value is easy, but when I try to calculate the derivative I get strange values.

I tried following the instructions for the `derivatives` command in the manual (http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/classEigen_1_1Spline.html#af3586ab1929959e0161bfe7da40155c6), and this is my attempt in code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/Splines>

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

double scaling(double x, double min, double max)  // for scaling numbers
{
    return (x - min)/(max - min);
}

VectorXd scale(VectorXd xvals)  // for scaling vectors
{
    const double min = xvals.minCoeff();
    const double max = xvals.maxCoeff();

    for (int k = 0; k < xvals.size(); k++)
        xvals(k) = scaling(xvals(k),min,max);

    return xvals;
}

int main()
{
    typedef Spline<double,1,3> spline;

    VectorXd xvals = (VectorXd(4) << 0,1,2,4).finished();
    VectorXd yvals = xvals.array().square();  // x^2

    spline testspline = SplineFitting<spline>::Interpolate(yvals.transpose(), 3,
scale(xvals).transpose());

    cout << "derivative at x = 0: " << testspline.derivatives(0.00,2) << endl;
    cout << "derivative at x = 1: " << testspline.derivatives(0.25,2) << endl;
    cout << "derivative at x = 2: " << testspline.derivatives(0.50,2) << endl;
    cout << "derivative at x = 3: " << testspline.derivatives(0.75,2) << endl;
    cout << "derivative at x = 4: " << testspline.derivatives(1.00,2) << endl;
}
```

it outputs

```
derivative at x = 0:  0  0 32
derivative at x = 1:  1  8 32
derivative at x = 2:  4 16 32
derivative at x = 3:  9 24 32
derivative at x = 4: 16 32 32
```

That is, the interpolation is correct (c.f. x = 3), but the derivatives are not, and they are off in a systematic way, so I'm thinking I'm doing something wrong. Since these follow x^2, the derivatives should be `0,2,4,6,8` and the second order derivative should be `2`.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

## Edit 1

Changing `x^2` to `x^2 + 1` yields the same derivatives, so that checks out at least. But changing `x^2` to `x^3` is wrong, but wrong in a slightly different way, output would then be:

```
derivative at x = 2:  8 48  192
derivative at x = 3: 27 108 288
derivative at x = 4: 64 192 384
```

Which is wrong, it should be `6, 9, 12`.

Also running the `x^2` case, but changing he input vector to `0,1,...9` yields the same derivative as using the original input vector, but the second order derivative becomes a steady `200`, which too is wrong. I fail to see why the second order derivative should depend on the number of input points.

Comment: The derivatives seem to be multiples of the "true" derivatives. In the x^2 case, they are 5 times what they should be, in the x^3 case they are 8, 12 and 16 times as big respectively.

Comment: Should the _Dim parameter of the Spline be 2 instead of 1?

Comment: @PaulH. If i understand the _Dim parameter correctly it's "calculate all derivatives up to this number", so, _Dim 2 would calculate the first and second order derivatives. In my output above the first column is the interpolated value, the second is the first order derivative and the third is the second order derivative.

Comment: I see. I haven't tried using the Spline functions yet, but they are an interest of mine. I thought I read that _Dim was the dimension of the curve such as 2d or 3d.

Comment: @PaulH., hey, you're actually right and I am wrong, sloppy of me to not to double check with the reference before replying. _Dim is the dimension of the spline. Still, that should be 1 as far as I can se? x^2 is a one dimensional curve, right?

Comment: You have x and y coordinates, so 2 dimensional. X squared is the function to calculate y. If you had a z coordinate it would be a 3d spline.

Comment: Trying to change _Dim to 2, I get a rather lengthy error message:
trying_eigen_spline: /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Block.h:148: Eigen::Block<XprType, BlockRows, BlockCols, InnerPanel>::Block(XprType&, Eigen::Index, Eigen::Index, Eigen::Index, Eigen::Index) [with XprType = Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, 1, -1, false>; int BlockRows = 1; int BlockCols = -1; bool InnerPanel = false; Eigen::Index = long int]: Assertion `startRow >= 0 && blockRows >= 0 && startRow <= xpr.rows() - blockRows && startCol >= 0 && blockCols >= 0 && startCol <= xpr.cols() - blockCols' failed.

Comment: I think it complains on me not supplying enough data? I'll look into it.

Comment: Like I said, I haven't used any of the Spline functions in Eigen yet, but after doing some calculations by hand, I see the results you are getting are the correct `y` coordinate derivatives of a Quadratic Bezier curve (degree 2). The control points of a Quadratic Bezier curve for the points given are `P_0 = (0, 0), P_1 = (2,0), P_2 = (4,16)`. Using the equations given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=B%C3%A9zier_curve&#Quadratic_B.C3.A9zier_curves) for the derivatives yields the results you are getting. `x` calculates to 4 for all the 1st derivatives and 0 for the 2nd.

Comment: Huh, that's a bit strange isn't it? So eigen's spline library really calculates quadratic bezier curves then?

Comment: No, they are b-splines, but your x^2 data can be represented by a single quadratic bezier segment, which I know how to calculate by hand. I'm still trying to wrap my head around b-spline calculations, but in this case both forms represent the same curve, so produce the same results. I think the confusion you are having is thinking that the first derivative (slope) of the curve at a particular point is just the derivative of x^2 (2x).

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking the same. At any rate, I ended up writing my own code to calculate the b-splines in the end. I'll post it as an answer when it is in a semi-presentable state.

Comment: I wrote a reply now, I didn't know how to tag you (you do deserve some credit for pointing out I had the wrong idea of _what_ Eigen was actually calculating), but there it is! Thanks for putting time into this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. You were very close. All you had to do was scale the derivatives
with

- `1 / (x_max - x_min)` (first derivative)
- `1 / (x_max - x_min)^2` (second derivative).

**TLDR**: You normalized the x values to be between 0 and 1 while fitting the spline, but you didn't scale the y values.

Instead of the spline fitting x^2, you actually fitted:

```
x_norm = (x - x_min) / (x_max - x_min)
y = x_norm**2
```

So using the chain rule the first derivative of `y = x_norm**2` would be `2x / (x_max - x_min)` and the second derivative would be `2 / (x_max - x_min)**2`.

Full example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/Splines>

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

VectorXd normalize(const VectorXd &x) {
  VectorXd x_norm;
  x_norm.resize(x.size());

  const double min = x.minCoeff();
  const double max = x.maxCoeff();
  for (int k = 0; k < x.size(); k++) {
    x_norm(k) = (x(k) - min)/(max - min);
  }

  return x_norm;
}

int main() {
  typedef Spline<double, 1, 3> Spline1D;
  typedef SplineFitting<Spline1D> Spline1DFitting;

  const Vector4d x{0, 1, 2, 4};
  const Vector4d y = (x.array().square());  // x^2

  const auto knots = normalize(x);  // Normalize x to be between 0 and 1
  const double scale = 1 / (x.maxCoeff() -  x.minCoeff());
  const double scale_sq = scale * scale;
  Spline1D spline = Spline1DFitting::Interpolate(y.transpose(), 3, knots);

  cout << "1st deriv at x = 0: " << spline.derivatives(0.00, 1)(1) * scale << endl;
  cout << "1st deriv at x = 1: " << spline.derivatives(0.25, 1)(1) * scale << endl;
  cout << "1st deriv at x = 2: " << spline.derivatives(0.50, 1)(1) * scale << endl;
  cout << "1st deriv at x = 3: " << spline.derivatives(0.75, 1)(1) * scale << endl;
  cout << "1st deriv at x = 4: " << spline.derivatives(1.00, 1)(1) * scale << endl;
  cout << endl;

  /**
   * IMPORTANT NOTE: Eigen's spline module is not documented well. Once you fit a spline
   * to find the derivative of the fitted spline at any point u [0, 1] you call:
   *
   *     spline.derivatives(u, 1)(1)
   *                        ^  ^  ^
   *                        |  |  |
   *                        |  |  +------- Access the result
   *                        |  +---------- Derivative order
   *                        +------------- Parameter u [0, 1]
   *
   * The last bit `(1)` is if the spline is 1D. And value of `1` for the first
   * order. `2` for the second order. Do not forget to scale the result.
   *
   * For higher dimensions, treat the return as a matrix and grab the 1st or
   * 2nd column for the first and second derivative.
   */

  cout << "2nd deriv at x = 0: " << spline.derivatives(0.00, 2)(2) * scale_sq << endl;
  cout << "2nd deriv at x = 1: " << spline.derivatives(0.25, 2)(2) * scale_sq << endl;
  cout << "2nd deriv at x = 2: " << spline.derivatives(0.50, 2)(2) * scale_sq << endl;
  cout << "2nd deriv at x = 3: " << spline.derivatives(0.75, 2)(2) * scale_sq << endl;
  cout << "2nd deriv at x = 4: " << spline.derivatives(1.00, 2)(2) * scale_sq << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
1st deriv at x = 0: 4.52754e-16
1st deriv at x = 1: 2
1st deriv at x = 2: 4
1st deriv at x = 3: 6
1st deriv at x = 4: 8

2nd deriv at x = 0: 2
2nd deriv at x = 1: 2
2nd deriv at x = 2: 2
2nd deriv at x = 3: 2
2nd deriv at x = 4: 2
```

Comment: Great! I have moved the accepted answer to this reply, since it actually resolves the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: see working .h-file for calculating B-splines of any order at the bottom.

Disclaimer: this is not an answer to my question as it is actually stated in the title, but rather a work-around with some comments.

After deliberations with user @Paul H. (see comments) I realized that my limited understanding of splines might have caused some confusion on my part. After some scrutiny of the Eigen documentation it seems plausible that the `derivative()` command does indeed works as intended, hence making my question badly phrased. The `derivative()` calculates the derivative of the *spline* rather than the derivative of the fitted *function*, as I intended it to. I have not figured out a way to get Eigen to output the function derivatives from the fit, and I don't think it is designed to to this. However, the derivatives can of course be readily calculated once the fitted points is obtained using some standard algorithm for calculating derivatives.

I wrote the following .h-file for calculating splines and their derivatives in the process which I thought worthwhile sharing. It's fairly well commented for convenience.

Note that this program uses 1-indexing rather than 0-indexing of the splines, hence for an e.g. quadratic B-spline `order` should be set to `4`. This is a small quirk that is be easily fixed by changing the calculations to match [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline).

### bsplines.h

```
//
// Header-file for calculating splines using standard libraries
//
//          usage:
//
//          x bsplines class constructs a set of splines up to some given order,
//            on some given knot sequence, the splines are stored in a vector,
//            such that splines[a][b] accesses the spline of order a and index b
//          x get<some_member>() is an accessor that returns a pointer to some 
//            data member of the spline
//          x calcsplines() calculates spline values as well as first and second 
//            order derivatives on some predefined grid
//          x calcspline() returns the spline value as well as first and second
//            derivatives in some point. This alborithm is slower than the grid
//            one, due to unnecessary recalculations of intermediate results
//          x writesplines() writes the splines and their derivatives to a file
//          x for more details se the class declaration below

//          TODO:
//          x change to 0-indexation
//          x introduce the possibility of calculating higher order  derivatives 
//            recursively
//
//          change log:
//
//          1.0     - initial release
//          1.1     - reworked grid such that the class now expects separate
//                  grid and knot files.
//                  - added the ability to calculate spline value in a point
//                  rather than calculate values on a grid
//                  - added a feature to change knots and grid
//          1.1.1   - reworked how returning single values works
//          1.1.2   - enabled swapping grid
//
// Note:
// 
// This file uses 1-indexation rathar than 0-indexation, hence a qubic spline
// would be k = 4. Someone should eventually fix this as this is non-standard.
//
// Also, while only standard libraries are used here, you might want to check out
// some linear algebra package (e.g. Armadillo or Eigen) if you're going to use the
// splines in a context where you need linear algebraic operations.
//
// Originally developed by David Andersson
//


#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>    
#include <fstream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
typedef unsigned int uint;

class bsplines                              // class for bsplines
{
    // private section
    
    uint order;                             // order of spline
    uint gridpts;                           // number of grid points
    uint knotpts;                           // number of knot points
    double tolerance;                       // tolerance for float comparisons

    vector<double> knots;                   // knot sequence
    vector<double> grid;                    // grid points
    
    class spline                            // a member spline in the set of splines
    {
        int index;                          // the spline index, or number
        
        vector<double> vals;                // spline values
        vector<double> d1;                  // spline first derivatives
        vector<double> d2;                  // spline second derivatives
        double tval;                        // same, but in one point
        double td1;
        double td2;
    
        friend bsplines;                    // for ease of access

        public:
    };
    
    vector<vector <spline>> splines;        // the set of splines

    // puclic section
    public:

    void readknots(string);                 // read knots from file
    void readknotsnorm(string);             // read knots from file and normalize
    void readgrid(string);                  // read grid from file
    void swapgrid(string);                  // reads and swaps new grid from file 
    void writesplines();                    // write spline vals and derivs to file
    void buildsplines();                    // build the set of splines
    void calcsplines();                     // calculate spline vals and derivs
    void printknots();                      // print knot sequence
    void printgrid();                       // print grid
    void printgridsize();                   // print gridsize
    void printvals(uint,uint);              // print values of a spline
    
    vector <double> calcspline(uint,uint,double); // calculate spline in point
    
    // accessors                            // returns pointer to member
    vector <double>* getknots(){return &knots;}
    vector <double>* getgrid(){return &grid;}
    uint* getknotpts(){return &knotpts;}
    uint* getgridpts(){return &gridpts;}
    uint getnosplines(uint m){return splines[m].size();}    
    vector <spline>* getsplines(uint m){return &splines[m];}
    vector <double>* getvals(uint m, uint n){return &splines[m][n].vals;}
    vector <double>* getd1(uint m, uint n){return &splines[m][n].d1;}
    vector <double>* getd2(uint m, uint n){return &splines[m][n].d2;}

    // constructor                          // sets up the spline class
    bsplines (string iknots, string igrid, uint iorder, double itol)
        :order(iorder), tolerance(itol)
    {
        readknots(iknots);
        readgrid(igrid);
        buildsplines();
    }
};

void bsplines::buildsplines()
{
    {
    for (uint l = 1; l <= order; l++)
        {
        vector <spline> splinevec;
            for (uint k = 0; k < knotpts - l; k++)
            {
                spline tmp;
                tmp.index = k;
                tmp.vals.reserve(gridpts);
                tmp.d1.reserve(gridpts);
                tmp.d2.reserve(gridpts);
                splinevec.push_back(tmp);
            }
            splines.push_back(splinevec);
        }
    }
}

vector <double> bsplines::calcspline(uint m, uint n, double x)
{
    // first order splines                  // exceptions handles infinities
    
    for (auto& sp : splines[0])
    {
        uint i = sp.index;
        
        if (x > knots[i+1])
            sp.tval = 0;
        else if ((x >= knots[i] && x < knots[i+1]) || x == knots.back())
            sp.tval = 1;
        else
            sp.tval = 0;
    }
    
    // higher order splines
    
    for (uint o = 1; o < order; o++)
    {
        uint oo = o+1;                      // compensating for 1-indexation
        for (auto& sp : splines[o])
        {
            uint i = sp.index;
            
            double t1 = knots[i+oo-1] - knots[i];
            double t2 = knots[i+oo] - knots[i+1];
            
            double c = 0;
                
            if (abs(t1) > tolerance)
                c += (x - knots[i]) / t1 * splines[o-1][i].tval;
            if (abs(t2) > tolerance)
                c += (knots[i+oo] - x) / t2 * splines[o-1][i+1].tval;

            sp.tval = c;
        }
    }
    
    uint o = order - 1; 
    
    // first order derivatives
    
    for (auto& sp : splines[o])
    {
        uint i = sp.index;
        
        double t1 = knots[i+order-1] - knots[i];
        double t2 = knots[i+order] - knots[i+1];
        
        double c = 0;
            
        if (abs(t1) > tolerance)
            c += 1.0 / t1 * splines[o-1][i].tval;
        if (abs(t2) > tolerance)
            c -= 1.0 / t2 * splines[o-1][i+1].tval;
            
        c *= (order-1);

        sp.td1 = c;
    }
        
    // second order derivatives
    
    for (auto& sp : splines[o])
    {
        uint i = sp.index;
        
        double t1 = (knots[i+order-1] - knots[i+0]) * (knots[i+order-2] - knots[i+0]);
        double t2 = (knots[i+order-1] - knots[i+0]) * (knots[i+order-1] - knots[i+1]);
        double t3 = (knots[i+order-0] - knots[i+1]) * (knots[i+order-1] - knots[i+1]);
        double t4 = (knots[i+order-0] - knots[i+1]) * (knots[i+order-0] - knots[i+2]);
        
            double c = 0;
            
        if (abs(t1) > tolerance)
            c += 1.0 / t1 * splines[o-2][sp.index].tval;
        if (abs(t2) > tolerance)
            c -= 1.0 / t2 * splines[o-2][sp.index+1].tval;
        if (abs(t3) > tolerance)
            c -= 1.0 / t3 * splines[o-2][sp.index+1].tval;
        if (abs(t4) > tolerance)
            c += 1.0 / t4 * splines[o-2][sp.index+2].tval;
            
        c *= (order-1)*(order-2);

        sp.td2 = c;
    }

    vector <double> retvals = {splines[m][n].tval, splines[m][n].td1, splines[m][n].td2};

    return retvals;
}

void bsplines::calcsplines()
{
    // first order splines
    
    for (auto& sp : splines[0])
    {
        uint i = sp.index;
        for (auto& x : grid)
        {
            if (x > knots[i+1])
                sp.vals.push_back(0);
            else if ((x >= knots[i] && x < knots[i+1]) || x == knots.back())
                sp.vals.push_back(1);
            else
                sp.vals.push_back(0);
        }
    }
    
    // higher order splines
    
    for (uint o = 1; o < order; o++)
    {
        uint oo = o+1;      // compensating for 1-indexation
        for (auto& sp : splines[o])
        {
            uint i = sp.index;
            
            double t1 = knots[i+oo-1] - knots[i];
            double t2 = knots[i+oo] - knots[i+1];
            
            for (auto& x : grid)
            {
                uint k = &x - &grid[0];
                
                double c = 0;
                
                if (abs(t1) > tolerance)
                    c += (x - knots[i]) / t1 * splines[o-1][i].vals[k];
                if (abs(t2) > tolerance)
                    c += (knots[i+oo] - x) / t2 * splines[o-1][i+1].vals[k];

                sp.vals.push_back(c);
            }
        }
    }
    
    uint o = order - 1;     // use this one when accessing splines;
    
    // first order derivatives
    
    for (auto& sp : splines[o])
    {
        uint i = sp.index;
        
        double t1 = knots[i+order-1] - knots[i];
        double t2 = knots[i+order] - knots[i+1];
        
        for (auto& x : grid)
        {
            uint k = &x - &grid[0];
            double c = 0;
            
            if (abs(t1) > tolerance)
                c += 1.0 / t1 * splines[o-1][i].vals[k];
            if (abs(t2) > tolerance)
                c -= 1.0 / t2 * splines[o-1][i+1].vals[k];
            
            c *= (order-1);

            sp.d1.push_back(c);
        }
    }
        
    // second order derivatives
    
    for (auto& sp : splines[o])
    {
        uint i = sp.index;
        
        double t1 = (knots[i+order-1] - knots[i+0]) * (knots[i+order-2] - knots[i+0]);
        double t2 = (knots[i+order-1] - knots[i+0]) * (knots[i+order-1] - knots[i+1]);
        double t3 = (knots[i+order-0] - knots[i+1]) * (knots[i+order-1] - knots[i+1]);
        double t4 = (knots[i+order-0] - knots[i+1]) * (knots[i+order-0] - knots[i+2]);
        
        for (auto& x : grid)
        {
            uint k = &x - &grid[0];
            double c = 0;
            
            if (abs(t1) > tolerance)
                c += 1.0 / t1 * splines[o-2][sp.index].vals[k];
            if (abs(t2) > tolerance)
                c -= 1.0 / t2 * splines[o-2][sp.index+1].vals[k];
            if (abs(t3) > tolerance)
                c -= 1.0 / t3 * splines[o-2][sp.index+1].vals[k];
            if (abs(t4) > tolerance)
                c += 1.0 / t4 * splines[o-2][sp.index+2].vals[k];
            
            c *= (order-1)*(order-2);

            sp.d2.push_back(c);
        }
    }
}

void bsplines::readknots(string knotfile)
{
    double x;

    ifstream readknots(knotfile);
    while (readknots >> x)
        knots.push_back(x);
    
    for (uint k = 0; k < order - 1; k++)
    {   
        knots.insert(knots.begin(),knots.front());
        knots.insert(knots.end(),knots.back());
    }

    knotpts = knots.size();
}

void bsplines::readknotsnorm(string knotfile)
{
    double x;
    knots.reserve(knotpts + 2*(order - 1));

    ifstream readknots(knotfile);
    while (readknots >> x)
        knots.push_back(x);
    
    auto minmax = minmax_element(begin(knots), end(knots));
    double min = *(minmax.first);
    double max = *(minmax.second);

    for (auto& el : knots)
        el = (el - min) / (max-min);
}

void bsplines::readgrid(string gridfile)
{
    double x;

    ifstream readgrid(gridfile);
    while (readgrid >> x)
        grid.push_back(x);
    
    gridpts = grid.size();
}

void bsplines::swapgrid(string gridfile)
{
    grid = {};
    double x;

    ifstream readgrid(gridfile);
    while (readgrid >> x)
        grid.push_back(x);
    
    gridpts = grid.size();
}

void bsplines::printknots()
{
    cout << "content in knot vector: " << endl;
    for (auto& el : knots)
        cout << el << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

void bsplines::printgrid()
{
    cout << "content in grid vector: " << endl;
    for (auto& el : grid)
        cout << el << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

void bsplines::printgridsize()
{
    cout << "number of grid points: " << endl << grid.size() << endl; 
}

void bsplines::printvals(uint m, uint n)
{
    cout << "content in spline (B" << m  << "," <<  n <<  ") vals vector: " << endl;
    for (auto& el : splines[n][m].vals)
        cout << el << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

void bsplines::writesplines()
{
    for (uint o = 0; o < order; o++)
        for (auto& sp : splines[o])
        {
            uint i = sp.index;
            ostringstream namestream;

            namestream << "B(" << fixed << setprecision(1) << i << "," 
                               << fixed << setprecision(1) << o << ").csv";
            string filename = namestream.str();
    
            ofstream fs;
            fs.open(filename);

            if (o < order - 1)
            {
                for (uint k = 0; k < sp.vals.size(); k++)
                    fs << sp.vals[k] << "," << 0 << "," << 0 << endl;
            
                fs.close();
            }
            else
            {
                for (uint k = 0; k < sp.vals.size(); k++)
                    fs << sp.vals[k] << "," << sp.d1[k] << "," << sp.d2[k] << endl;
                fs.close();
            }

            cout << "write " << sp.vals.size() << " numbers to " << filename << endl;
        }
}
```

Edit: updated .h-file.